# Why is my unordered list getting pushed to the right side?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I know next to nothing about HTML, and even less about CSS, and dear lord what I wouldn't give for a WYSIWYG editor that makes this stuff easier!

I simply can't understand why the unordered list I have created does not appear directly underneath the text above it!

[image]

I've placed the relevant snippits in jsbin

https://jsbin.com/kebidikozu/edit?html,output

And here is the code in question:

```css
.upper {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 170px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.downwarning {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: gray;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.5/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.5/flowbite.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper" id="upperid">

<span class="downwarning">this is just some text i right now it really doesnt matter what is says but WHY OH WHY is my haiku UL getting pushed to the right?:
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>It's not DNS</li> 
      <li>There is no way it is DNS</li>
      <li>It was DNS</li>
    </ul>
  </span>

</div>
```

If anyone can let me know why this format nightmare is happening it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put the `<ul>` tag inside the `<span>` tag the list display after the text , if you close the `<span>` tag and then write `<ul>` tag, the list appears under the text.

```
<span class="downwarning">
this is just some text i right now it really doesnt matter what is says but WHY OH WHY is my haiku UL getting pushed to the right?:
</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>It's not DNS</li> 
      <li>There is no way it is DNS</li>
      <li>It was DNS</li>
    </ul>
```

If you don't want to change the html you can remove the `display: flex` in css.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thank you very much Andish!

I swear HTML and CSS is way, way more complicated than writing a python app with Flask. I've got 80 lines of code and 293 lines of HTML and CSS!!!